# Using "between" to introduce a set of traits or circumstances

Tags: phrases, prepositions, agreement, adverbials

I was wondering if this construction using "between" to introduce a set of traits/circumstances was correct. (I'm also interested in alternative phrases that may be more appropriate):

> Between his spirit, talent, amiability, and tenacity, I believe he will thrive in this role.

> Between the rain and the pandemic, going outside is probably not a good idea.

Does this make sense? If so, when I use this construction, what does "between" need to agree with? (i.e. is it "between his X, Y, and Z, I believe he will..." or is it "between his X, Y, and Z, he will..."

I don't know if this is actually a colloquialism, but I've definitely heard/seen this somewhere and wanted to know if it'd be understandable to any English speaker, as well as guidelines for proper grammatical usage.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact focus of your question. There is nothing unusual about this introductory dependent clause as opposed to any other. *Between [some list of two or more things], [something else].* What comes before *[something else]* has no effect on the grammar of *[something else]*. It's sense 6 of Merriam-Webster's definition of [*between*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between): "taking together the combined effect of // *between* work and family life, they have no time for hobbies."

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks! I wanted to make sure it was a formal construction. Regarding grammar, I see such agreement issues often. For instance, we say "With a PhD in economics, he'd be a great fit" instead of "With a PhD in economics, I think he's a great fit." I wasn't sure if "between" followed similar rules.

Comment: By "agreement issues," are you talking about misplaced modifiers? You could certainly say that. But that's true of any introductory dependent clause, not only this particular one. Are you asking about misplaced modifiers in general?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-among-and-between/